# Featured content on index, rails 4 - postgreSQL Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I had managed to allow posts to be featured (admin side), but I had some problems displaying them on the index view.

Note: with sqlite works fine, but on heroku with pg, doesn't work as expected.

Note2: featured_post is a string (it has "no" or "yes", "no" by default).

**My model post.rb**

```
    scope :featured, -> { order(featured_post: :asc, created_at: :desc).limit(100) } #pg
  else
    scope :featured, -> { order(featured_post: :desc, created_at: :desc).limit(100) } #sqlite
  end
```

**My controller posts_controller.rb**

```
    if params[:search]
      @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page],  :per_page => 20)
    else  
      @posts = Post.all.featured
    end
  end
```

With SQLite the "featured posts" are shown on top, and ordered by DESC no matter if the post is older. So it works as expected, everything OK. For example:

1. Title One : 21.12.2014 **featured**
2. Title Two : 09.22.2008 **featured**
3. Title three : 02.01.2015 (today)
4. Title four : 01.01.2015 (yesterday)

**featured** is on top and ordered by date (recent featured first).

With PostgreSQL on Heroku, it gives me some problems. For example:

1. Title One : 02.01.2015 (today) **not featured** (but it show on top)
2. Title Two : 21.12.2014 **featured**
3. Title Three : 09.22.2008 **featured**
4. Title Four : 02.01.2015 (today)
5. Title Five : 01.01.2015 (yesterday)

**featured** is not on top when new post (default "no" featured) is created. The ordering by date is ok, as you see, but it "doesn't" stay on top, when a new post is created.

Had to say that I tried DESC and DESC or ASC and ASC or DESC and ASC, etc on heroku postgresql, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After half a day searching and trying to make the **featured** posts stay on top and order by recent, I had managed to find a solution (it's not the best, but it is a "temporarily a solution". Here is what I did:

**Model post.rb**

```
scope :featured, -> { where(featured_post: 'yes').order(created_at: :desc) }
scope :unfeatured, -> { where(featured_post: 'no').order(created_at: :desc) }
```

**Controller posts_controller.rb**

```
@posts_featured = Post.all.featured
@posts_unfeatured = Post.all.unfeatured
```

**View index.html.erb**

*featured*

```
<% @posts_featured.each do |post| %>
  <header><h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, html_css_show_path(post) %></h2></header>
  <div><%= post.body %></div>
<% end %>
```

*unfeatured*

```
<% @posts_unfeatured.each do |post| %>
  <header><h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, html_css_show_path(post) %></h2></header>
  <div><%= post.body %></div>
<% end %>
```

And that made the trick. Again, it is not a great solution but it got me out of the problem for the moment. Hope that can help someone else. Btw, I'm using **rails 4.1.8** on **ruby 2.1.4**.